# SAP Solution Manager endpoint configuration in WSO2ESB

Tags: web-services, sap-solution-manager, wso2-esb

I use the webservice interface ICT_SERVICE_DESK_API from SAP Solution Manager.
I activate the webservice in SAP. I get a connection with the tool soapui.

But I have no idea how i configure the endpoint in the WSO2ESB.
Until now I configure a proxyservie. There I generate a soap message which send over a adress endpoint to the webservice from SAP.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><urn:RequestGuid xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem is that i get something back. This is not useful.
Then I want change the adress endpoint to wdsl endpoint.

How can I configure the endpoint from the wso2esb for the webservice from sap?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following resources to find information on how you can configure endpoints in WSO2 ESB.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Endpoints.

I think the reason for not getting the expected response from SAP web service is, you might not be sending the correct request to the SAP web service through the Proxy service.

You can either construct the expected request message format inside the Proxy Service or you can send the request in the correct format from the client which invoke the proxy service.

If you can provide me more information on the problem including the wsdl of the SAP web service I may able to help you.